# Searching for an object index in NSArray using an inline block

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, objective-c-blocks, css

I've seen a few examples around using NSArray indexOfObjectPassingTest, but I could not make them work (they would not return a valid index).
So now I'm trying using an inline block. I have done it by typedef'ing a block, then setting it as a property, synthesizing it, and initializing it in the constructor.
However that sort of renders the whole point mute, as I could easily create a method and use it instead (less typing, less effort).

What I'm trying to achieve is something along this:

```
Observations *obs = [self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS objectAtIndex: ^NSInteger (NSString *keyword){ 
    for (Observations *obs in self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS) {
        if ([obs.TIME isEqualToString:keyword] == YES) return (NSInteger)[self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS indexOfObject:obs];
    }
    return (NSInteger)-1;
}];
```

However Xcode simply won't have it. I've tried different variations, but declaring it inline seems to be a problem, which is weird, because as I've said, typedefing it, declaring, and synthesizing it works like this:

```
Observations *obs = [self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS objectAtIndex:findObs(keyword)];
```

Where findObs is again a defined block that does the same thing.
Is this a syntax issue, or am I missing something else more important ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`-objectAtIndex:` takes an `NSUInteger` as a parameter, but you're passing it a block (denoted by the `^`). Your second example calls `findObs` (which may be your block) with the `keyword` argument, passing the *result* of that call to `-objectAtIndex:`.

You probably want to combine `-objectAtIndex:` with `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:`:

```
NSString *keyword = /* whatever */;
NSArray *array = self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS;
NSUInteger idx = [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){ 
    Observations *obs = (Observations*)obj;
    return [obs.TIME  isEqualToString:keyword];
}];
if (idx != NSNotFound)
    Observations *obs = [array objectAtIndex:idx];
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. So, I take it that passing an inline block as an NSInteger parameter (essentially expecting the block's return value to be passed as parameter) is not doable, unless its type defined and synthesized ?

Comment: You could also call your block in-line: `[... objectAtIndex:(^NSInteger (NSString *k){ ... })(keyword)];`, but things start looking a bit messy.

Comment: This example will return the last object passing the test in the array.
To stop iteration as soon as the first object is found, you must set `*stop` to `YES`

Comment: There's normally no need to iterate the array twice by following the first search by an objectAtIndex call…

Comment: @TristanLeblanc The example returns the first object---[`indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObjectPassingTest:) stops iterating when `*stop` is set to `YES` ***or*** the predicate returns `YES`. Also, `objectAtIndex:` is an O(1) operation and does not iterate through the array.

Comment: Yes, @一二三 sorry - it's a type error. I've provided an answer at below without fault - You're almost right for objectAtIndex:  - it does not necessarily ;)  But it is much faster anyway, since it's an address comparison.

Answer (score 7):

This is an example that returns the index of a string in an array of strings. It may be adapted to any kind of object.

```
NSString* myString = @"stringToFind";
NSUInteger objectIndex = [myStringArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return (*stop = ([obj isEqualToString:myString]));
    }];
```

To answer the original question precisely:

```
NSString *keyword = @"myKeyword";
NSUInteger index = [self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) { 
    return (*stop = [(Observations*)obs.TIME  isEqualToString:keyword]);
}];
Observations *obs = (index!=NSNotFound) ? self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS[index] : NULL;
```

*But it's quite strange to compare something called TIME with a keyword…* ;)

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to typedef or synthesize anything to make your second example work--just return the block from a method, which would look like this:

```
-(NSUInteger(^)(NSArray *, NSString *))findObs {
    return ^(NSArray *array, NSString *keyword) {
        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
            Observations *obs = [array objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([obs.TIME isEqualToString:keyword]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return NSNotFound;
    };
}

Observations *obs = [self.myAppointment.OBSERVATIONS objectAtIndex:[self findObs](keyword)];
```

Here are some [good reasons for defining blocks as method return values, rather than inline](http://twobitlabs.com/2012/05/block-initialization-for-testability-and-reuse/).

Comment: you need to copy the block you're returning, unless you're using ARC which does it for you

Comment: Yes, @user102008, that's correct. I generally assume ARC these days, unless it's clear from someone's code sample that they're not using ARC.